# Is there a way in JQuery to iterate through an array of strings and return new arrays that sort out the matching strings in that array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm just learning jQuery and this is one of my first projects so apologies if this is an easy question.

So let’s say I have an array like this:

```
const array = ["electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water", "electric", "water", "electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water"];
```

I want to be able to return 4 new arrays in this case like below:

```
[“electric”, “electric”, “electric”, “electric”, “electric”]
[“fire”, “fire”]
[“flying”, “flying”]
[“water”, “water”, “water”]
```

I’ve tried reading through the different array methods and some of the previously asked questions here but I don’t see anything that relates to this.

Comment: In JS you can't return 4 values, but you can return an array of values, if it is ok for you

Comment: Note that jQuery is primarily intended for amending the DOM. What you're attempting to do is to sort and separate an array, so you need just plain JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `map` to group the items:

```js
const array = ["electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water", "electric", "water", "electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water"];
let map = {};
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     let item = array[i];
     if(!map[item])
          map[item] = [ item ];
     else
          map[item].push(item);
}
console.log(Object.values(map));
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I can take it from here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the array for each element to create an array of arrays.

```js
const array = ["electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water", "electric", "water", "electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water"];
const res = Object.values(
     array.reduce(
      (acc,curr)=>((acc[curr]=acc[curr]||[]).push(curr), acc), {}
     )
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const array = ["electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water", "electric", "water", "electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water"]

console.log(array.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el.charAt(0)] = acc[el.charAt(0)] ? [...acc[el.charAt(0)], el] : [el]; 
    return acc
}, {}))
```

You `reduce` the element, and you build the resulting object based on:

1. if there is already a entry for that first letter, push the current element
2. otherwise, associate to that entry the current first letter and an array with only the current element

NOTE: you can actually reduce it to an associative array, is up to you which one matches your requirements better

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hope you like it here. Feel free to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and checkout how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

You can use the array `.map()` and `.filter()` methods - you really don't need jQuery for this - as follows:

```
let chunks = array.map(a => array.filter(x => x === a))
    .filter((item, index) => array.indexOf(item[0]) === index);
```

```js
const array = ["electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water", "electric", "water", "electric", "fire", "flying", "electric", "water"];
let chunks = array.map(a => array.filter(x => x === a)).filter((item, i) => array.indexOf(item[0]) === i);

console.log( chunks );
```